# Mongoose post init async not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, hook

Mongoose post 'init' is apparently unable to perform asynchronously as documented. I'm using the latest mongoose@5.0.10 and @types/mongoose@5.0.7 packages.

```
schema.post('init', function (doc, next: any) {
    gunzipJSON(this.zipped).then(obj => {
        this.categories = deserialize<Category[]>(Category, obj) || [];
        next();
    });
});
```

Also note my use of "next: any" to avoid a TS2349 error below on call to *next()*. When the hook fires, this and doc are set to a model. Before I upgraded to latest, I was using Mongoose 4.7.21 and *next* was supplied with a *function(err)* as expected, but the TS declaration must have been wrong.

Still, when the init hook function returns, the Mongoose init caller doesn't wait for my async decompression to complete and immediately returns the document to my client. When the decompression finishes, it correctly inflates and deserializes the field but it's too late. What am I doing wrong? I've tried numerous permutations of hook parameters to trigger async behavior without luck. Of course this happens when you're in a time crunch!

**UPDATE**:

I just now read 5.0 release notes  https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/master/migrating_to_5.md: "init hooks are now fully synchronous and do not receive next() as a parameter. Document.prototype.init() no longer takes a callback as a parameter. It was always synchronous, just had a callback for legacy reasons."

Yikes! How does one apply post load async hooks?

Comment: Using the synchronous version, zlib.gunzipSync(), did the trick. Too bad this hook cannot be async.